# An API to remove applications on mobile device or modify their permissions?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is there any way (existing API) to remotely remove applications on mobile device or modify their permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Admin SDK does not contain this functionality. You could however [monitor a list of installed applications on the user's device](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/get) and if a disallowed application is installed on the device, [block sync for the device](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/action) and email the user explaining why sync has been blocked and that they'll need to uninstall to re-enable sync.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any way to find out whether Google is going to provide such API in near future or not.

Comment: I do not know of any announced plans by Google to allow admin removal of user-installed apps. The only thing I can point to is the hidden feature in Android 4.3 that allows users to remove permissions from an app: http://goo.gl/EtIhR2